# How to remove tr from different dynamic-tables with a single button click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two tables with unique ids, each table have their 1st two rows (`tr`) filled with some data, I have provided a button named `Add More` on the `th` of the 1st table that shows a Bootstrap modal to add extra product details and product colour information.

I get the data from the modal `onSubmit` and use it to dynamically populate the two tables using their ids, using a count I get the ids on these `tr` to change as I want.

I have a remove button on both tables but hide the remove button on the 2nd table, so when the remove button in the 1st table is clicked I want it to remove the same corresponding `tr` from the 2nd table, but that is not happening.

I have tried several ways, sometimes it removes only in table 1 but not table 2 and sometimes too it completely removes all the `tr` from both tables if the `tr`s are more than one.

So how to remove `tr` from different dynamic-tables with a single button click using jQuery?

I need it so that the user do not mistakenly remove a different row from the 2nd table, because they correspond to each other.

Please note that am not getting a CDN for the Bootstrap colorpicker so it's not working at the moment, so don't select the POWDER COATING option.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    function onChangeColor(getID, getSelectcolor, getShowColorInput, wh) {

      if (getID == 'POWDER COATING') {
        getSelectcolor.hide();

        var html = '';

        if (wh == 'M') {
          html += '<label for="" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Select color</label>';
          html += '<div class="col-md-6 in">';
          html += '<input id="colorInputM" placeholder="Enter color code" name="colorInput_R1[]" value="" type="text" class="form-control">';
          html += '</div>';
          getShowColorInput.html(html);
          getShowColorInput.show();
          $('#colorInputM').colorpicker({
            color: "#a1713a",
            horizontal: true
          });

        } else {
          html += '<div class="col-md-6">';
          html += '<input id="colorInput" placeholder="Enter color code" name="colorInput_R1[]" value="" type="text" class="form-control">';
          html += '</div>';
          getShowColorInput.html(html);
          getShowColorInput.show();
          $('#colorInput').colorpicker({
            color: "#a1713a",
            horizontal: true
          });

        }
      } else {
        getSelectcolor.show();
        getShowColorInput.hide();

      }
    }

    var MaxProducts = 100; // Maximum products and Railings allowed to be added.

    var AddProductCount = 2; // To keep track of the products; Start from 2 since there is will be 1 already there.
    var AddProductColorCount = 2; // To keep track of the product color; Start from 2 since there is will be 1 already there.
    var AddRailingCount = 2; // To keep track of the railings; Start from 2 since there is will be 1 already there.

    var AddProdToTable = $("#addProd"); // Don't confuse this with database but it html table for the product
    var addProdLegth = AddProdToTable.length + 1; // Initial Field Count

    var AddProdColorToTable = $("#addProductColor"); // Don't confuse this with database but it html table for the product color
    var addProdColorLegth = AddProdColorToTable.length + 1; // Initial Field Count

    var AddRailingToDiv = $("#addRailings"); // Add a the railing
    var addRailingLegth = AddRailingToDiv.length + 1; // Initial Field Count


    // To get the addProd button which was click
    var addProdButton = $(".adProd");

    // To add a product and the rest.

    $(addProdButton).click(function() {

      $('#railingNos').val(addProdLegth);

      $('#addMoreProductModal').modal('show');

      // }

    });

    $('#amp').on('submit', function(e) {

      e.preventDefault();

      var prodname = $('#prodname').val();
      var prodtype = $('#prodtype').val();
      var prodcover = $('#prodcover').val();
      var hand = $('#hand').val();
      var prodcolortype = $('#productColorN').val();
      var prodcolorname = $('#colorN').val();
      var prodcolorinput = $('#colorInputM').val();

      function getWhich() {
        if (prodcolorname != null) {
          return prodcolorname;
        } else if (prodcolorinput != null) {
          return prodcolorinput;
        }
      }
      // alert(getWhich());

      function returnCover() {
        if (prodcover == null) {
          return '';
        } else {
          return prodcover;
        }

      }

      var html = '';

      html += '<tr id="' + AddProductCount + '">';
      html += '<td>Product Name ' + AddProductCount + '.' + '</td>';
      html += '<td>';
      html += '<select required name="productName[]" type="text" class="form-control" id="productName_R' + AddProductCount + '">';
      html += '<option value="';
      html += prodname;
      html += '">';
      html += prodname;
      html += '</option>';
      html += '</select></td>';
      html += '<td>';
      html += '<select required type="text" class="form-control " name="productType[]" id="productType_R' + AddProductCount + '">';
      html += '<option value="' + prodtype + '">';
      html += prodtype;
      html += '</option>';
      html += '</select></td>';
      html += '<td>';
      html += '<select name="productCover[]" id="productCover_R' + AddProductCount + '" type="text" class="form-control" >';
      html += '<option value="' + prodcover + '">';
      html += returnCover();
      html += '</option>';
      html += '</select>';
      html += '</td>';
      html += '<td>';
      html += '<select required name="handRail[]" type="text" id="handRail_R' + AddProductCount + '" class="form-control">';
      html += '<option value="' + hand + '">';

      html += hand;
      html += '</option>';
      html += '</select>';
      html += '</td>';
      html += '<td><button type="button" id="' + AddProductCount + '" class="btn btn-danger remove0"><span>Remove</span></button></td>';
      html += '</tr>';

      $(AddProdToTable).append(html);

      html = '';

      // To add product colour
      // var htmlColor = '';

      html += '<tr id="' + AddProductColorCount + '">';
      html += '<td>Product Colour ' + AddProductColorCount + '.' + '</td>';
      html += '<td>';
      html += '<select type="text" class="form-control" required name="productColor[]" id="productColor_R' + AddProductColorCount + '">';
      html += '<option value="' + prodcolortype + '">' + prodcolortype + '</option>';
      html += '</select>';
      html += '</td>';

      html += '<td colspan="4">';
      html += '<div id="selectColor_R' + AddProductColorCount + '">';
      html += '<select type="text" class="form-control" name="color[]" id="color_R' + AddProductColorCount + '">';
      html += '<option value="' + getWhich() + '">' + getWhich() + '</option>';
      html += '</select>';
      html += '</div>';
      html += '</td>';
      html += '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove1"><span>Remove</span></button></td>';
      html += '</tr>';
      $(AddProdColorToTable).append(html);
      addProdLegth++;
      AddProductCount++;

      addProdColorLegth++
      AddProductColorCount++


      // To add railing

      $('#addMoreProductModal').modal('hide');
      $('#amp').trigger("reset");

      return false;

    });

    function removeColor() {
      $(".remove1").trigger('click');

      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
      addProdColorLegth--;
      AddProductColorCount--;

      return false;



    }


    $("body").on("click", ".remove0", function() {

      var gid = $(this).prop('id');
      var ind = "tr:gt(" + gid + ")";
      // console.log(ind);
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();

      addProdLegth--;
      AddProductCount--;

      removeColor();

      return false;

    });



    // Adding the hand rail to the railing based on selected hand rail at the top
    $('#handRail_R1').change(function() {

      $('#accesHandRail1_R1').html('<option value="' + $("#handRail_R1").val() + '">' + $("#handRail_R1").val() + '</option>');
    }).change();

    // Adding the product type to the railing based on selected product at the top
    $('#productType_R1').change(function() {

      $('#brackSideCover1_R1').html('<option value="' + $("#productType_R1").val() + '">' + $("#productType_R1").val() + '</option>');
    }).change();

    // First time of selecting a color.
    $("#productColor_R1").change(function() {

      var getID = $(this).val();
      var getSelectcolor = $('#selectColor_R1');
      var getShowColorInput = $('#ShowColorInput_R1');
      var wh = 'F';
      onChangeColor(getID, getSelectcolor, getShowColorInput, wh);

    });

    // Using the modal to add more colors.
    $("#productColorN").change(function() {

      var getID = $(this).val();
      var getSelectcolor = $('#selectColorN');
      var getShowColorInput = $('#ShowColorInputN');
      var wh = 'M';
      onChangeColor(getID, getSelectcolor, getShowColorInput, wh);
      // 

    });

  }); // End here
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/itsjavi/bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js"></script>
<link href="https://github.com/itsjavi/bootstrap-colorpicker/dist/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  function products(s5, s6) {

    var vr = /CONTINUE/;
    var vr1 = /BRACKET/;

    var proname = document.getElementById(s5).value;

    var protype = document.getElementById(s6);

    protype.innerHTML = "";

    if (vr.test(proname)) {
      var nw = proname.split(" ");
      var nw1 = nw[0] + ' ' + nw[1] + ' ' + nw[2];
      var nw2 = nw1 + " FULL PROFILE" + ' | ' + "FULL PROFILE";
      var nw3 = nw1 + " BRACKET WISE" + ' | ' + "BRACKET WISE";

      var optionAray = [" | Select type"];
      optionAray.push(nw2, nw3);
    } else if (vr1.test(proname) && proname != "SEA LINE BRACKET PROFILE") {

      var nw = proname.split(" ");
      var nw1 = nw[0] + ' ' + nw[1];
      // var nw2 = nw1+" FULL PROFILE"+' | '+"FULL PROFILE";
      var nw3 = nw1 + " BRACKET WISE" + ' | ' + "BRACKET WISE";
      var optionAray = [" | Select type"];
      optionAray.push(nw3);

    } else if (proname == "SEA LINE BRACKET PROFILE") {

      var nw = proname.split(" ");
      var nw1 = nw[0] + ' ' + nw[1] + ' ' + nw[2];
      // var nw2 = nw1+" BRACKET PROFILE"+' | '+"BRACKET PROFILE";
      var nw3 = nw1 + " FULL SIDE CLIP" + ' | ' + "FULL SIDE CLIP";
      var optionAray = [" | Select type"];
      optionAray.push(nw3);

    }

    for (var option in optionAray) {
      var pair = optionAray[option].split("|");
      var newOption = document.createElement("option");
      newOption.value = pair[0];
      newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
      protype.options.add(newOption);
    }
  }


  function productscover(s7, s8) {

    var vrcon = /CONTINUE/;
    var vrbrack = /BRACKET/;
    var sid = /SIDE/;
    var s7 = document.getElementById(s7).value;

    var s8 = document.getElementById(s8);

    s8.innerHTML = "";

    if (vrcon.test(s7)) {
      var optionArray = [];


    } else if (sid.test(s7)) {

      var optionArray = ["CONCEALED TUBE | CONCEALED TUBE"];
    } else if (vrbrack.test(s7) || vrcon.test(s7)) {

      var optionArray = ["FULL SIDE COVER | FULL SIDE COVER", "BRACKET WISE SIDE COVER | BRACKET WISE SIDE COVER"];
      // optionArray += [];

    }


    for (var option in optionArray) {
      var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
      var newOption = document.createElement("option");
      newOption.value = pair[0];
      newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
      s8.options.add(newOption);
    }
  }


  // colors
  function colorType(col1, col2) {

    var col1 = document.getElementById(col1);
    var col2 = document.getElementById(col2);
    col2.innerHTML = "";
    if (col1.value == "ANODISED") {
      var optionArray = ["Silver | Silver", "Gold | Gold", "Champagne | Champagne", "Special | Special", "RAL | RAL"];
    } else if (col1.value == "PVDF") {
      var optionArray = ["Silver | Silver", "Gold | Gold", "Champagne | Champagne", "Special | Special"];
    } else if (col1.value == "WOODEN") {
      var optionArray = ["Light | Light", "Dark | Dark", "Medium | Medium", "Special | Special"];
    } else if (col1.value == "MILL FINISH") {
      var optionArray = ["Raw | Raw"];
    }

    for (var option in optionArray) {
      var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
      var newOption = document.createElement("option");
      newOption.value = pair[0];
      newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
      col2.options.add(newOption);
    }
  }
</script>

<!-- Modal starts here -->

<div class="modal fade" id="addMoreProductModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #5F9EA0">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Product</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                              <span aria-hidden="true" style="color: red;">Cancel</span>
                            </button>
      </div>


      <form method="POST" id="amp">


        <fieldset>
          <center>
            <legend>Add More Product </legend>
          </center>
          <hr>

          <div class="card-body">

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="prodname" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Product Name</label>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <select required name="prodname" type="text" class="form-control" id="prodname" onchange="products(this.id,'prodtype'); productscover('prodtype','prodcover')">
                  <option value="TextingPN">Select product name</option>
                  <option value="SMART LINE CONTINUE PROFILE">SMART LINE</option>
                  <option value="SEA LINE BRACKET PROFILE">SEA LINE</option>
                  <option value="SQUARE LINE BRACKET PROFILE">SQUARE LINE</option>
                  <option value="SLIM LINE CONTINUE PROFILE">SLIM LINE</option>
                  <option value="SMALL LINE CONTINUE PROFILE">SMALL LINE</option>
                  <option value="STAR LINE BRACKET PROFILE">STAR LINE</option>
                  <option value="SKY LINE BRACKET PROFILE">SKY LINE</option>
                  <option value="SPARK LINE BRACKET PROFILE">SPARK LINE</option>
                  <option value="SLEEK LINE CONTINUE PROFILE">SLEEK LINE</option>
                  <option value="SUPER LINE CONTINUE PROFILE">SUPER LINE</option>
                  <option value="SIGNATURE LINE CONTINUE PROFILE">SIGNATURE LINE</option>
                </select>

              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row brckshow"></div>

            <div class="form-group row">
              <label for="prodtype" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Product Type</label>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <select required type="text" class="form-control" name="prodtype" id="prodtype" onchange="productscover(this.id,'prodcover')">
                  <option value="TextingPN">Product type</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">

              <label for="prodcover" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Product Cover:</label>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <select name="prodcover" id="prodcover" type="text" class="form-control">
                  <option value="TextingPN">Product cover</option>

                </select>

              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">

              <label for="hand" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Hand Rail:</label>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <select required="" name="hand" id="hand" type="text" class="form-control ">
                  <option value="TextingPN">Select hand rail</option>
                  <option value="ROUND HAND RAIL">ROUND</option>
                  <option value="SQUARE HAND RAIL">SQUARE</option>
                  <option value="SMALL HAND RAIL">SMALL</option>
                  <option value="SLIM HAND RAIL">SLIM</option>
                  <option value="EDGE GUARD HAND RAIL">EDGE GUARD</option>
                  <option value="HALF ROUND HAND RAIL">HALF ROUND</option>
                  <option value="RECTANGLE HAND RAIL">RECTANGLE</option>
                  <option value="INCLINE HAND RAIL">INCLINE</option>

                </select>

              </div>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="" value="" id="railingNos">


            <div class="form-group row">

              <label for="hand" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Color:</label>
              <div class="col-md-6">

                <select type="text" class="form-control" required name="productColorN" id="productColorN" onchange="colorType(this.id,'colorN')">
                  <option value="TextingPN">Select colour</option>
                  <option value="ANODISED">ANODISED</option>
                  <option value="PVDF">PVDF</option>
                  <option value="WOODEN">WOODEN</option>
                  <option value="MILL FINISH">MILL FINISH</option>
                  <option value="POWDER COATING">POWDER COATING</option>
                </select>

              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row" id="selectColorN">

              <label for="colorN" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"> Color Type</label>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <select type="text" class="form-control" name="colorN" id="colorN">
                  <option value="TextingPN">Select colour</option>


                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row" id="ShowColorInputN">
              <!-- if powerder coating is selected then show an input box to enter -->


            </div>



            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger " data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>


              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal ends here -->

<!-- The main table -->
<table border="1" id="addProd">
  <tr style="background-color: #f5f5f5; font-size: 16px;">
    <th colspan="6" width="1500">
      <center>Final Product Details</center>
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Product Name 1.</td>
    <td>
      <select required name="productName[]" type="text" class="form-control" id="productName_R1" onchange="products(this.id,'productType_R1'); productscover('productType_R1','productCover_R1')">
        <option value="">Select product name</option>
        <option value="SMART LINE CONTINUE PROFILE">SMART LINE</option>
        <option value="SEA LINE BRACKET PROFILE">SEA LINE</option>
        <option value="SQUARE LINE BRACKET PROFILE">SQUARE LINE</option>
        <option value="SLIM LINE CONTINUE PROFILE">SLIM LINE</option>
        <option value="SMALL LINE CONTINUE PROFILE">SMALL LINE</option>
        <option value="STAR LINE BRACKET PROFILE">STAR LINE</option>
        <option value="SKY LINE BRACKET PROFILE">SKY LINE</option>
        <option value="SPARK LINE BRACKET PROFILE">SPARK LINE</option>
        <option value="SLEEK LINE CONTINUE PROFILE">SLEEK LINE</option>
        <option value="SUPER LINE CONTINUE PROFILE">SUPER LINE</option>
        <option value="SIGNATURE LINE CONTINUE PROFILE">SIGNATURE LINE</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select required type="text" class="form-control" name="productType[]" id="productType_R1" onchange="productscover(this.id,'productCover_R1')">
        <option value="">Product type</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select name="productCover[]" id="productCover_R1" type="text" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Product cover</option>

      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select required name="handRail[]" id="handRail_R1" type="text" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select hand rail</option>
        <option value="ROUND HAND RAIL">ROUND</option>
        <option value="SQUARE HAND RAIL">SQUARE</option>
        <option value="SMALL HAND RAIL">SMALL</option>
        <option value="SLIM HAND RAIL">SLIM</option>
        <option value="EDGE GUARD HAND RAIL">EDGE GUARD</option>
        <option value="HALF ROUND HAND RAIL">HALF ROUND</option>
        <option value="RECTANGLE HAND RAIL">RECTANGLE</option>
        <option value="INCLINE HAND RAIL">INCLINE</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>

      <button style="float: center;" type="button" id="btn_R1" class="btn btn-info btn-sm adProd"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>Add More Products</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<!-- for space -->
<table border="1" id="addProductColor">
  <tr style="background-color: #f5f5f5; font-size: 16px;">
    <th colspan="6" width="1500">
      <center>&emsp;</center>
    </th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Product Colour 1.</td>
    <td>
      <select type="text" class="form-control" required name="productColor[]" id="productColor_R1" onchange="colorType(this.id,'color_R1')">
        <option value="">Select colour</option>
        <option value="ANODISED">ANODISED</option>
        <option value="PVDF">PVDF</option>
        <option value="WOODEN">WOODEN</option>
        <option value="MILL FINISH">MILL FINISH</option>
        <option value="POWDER COATING">POWDER COATING</option>
      </select>

    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="selectColor_R1">
        <select type="text" class="form-control" name="color[]" id="color_R1">

        </select>
      </div>
      <div id="ShowColorInput_R1">
        <!-- if powerder coating is selected then show an input box to enterccolor  code-->
      </div>
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
<div id="addRailings">

</div>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There's a lot of code there - maybe try to whittle it down to a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), maybe in JSFiddle, so it is easy for ppl to see and understand the problem.  You might find the problem yourself in the process!

Comment: I have done so for days, but all the same am still looking at getting it. Thanks for checking it.